# Dynamically change form action to spawn an iframe

Tags: javascript, forms, iframe

I'm trying to dynamically change the action of a form so that it spawns an iframe instead of posting to the next page. Here is my code:

```
var formItem = document.getElementsByTagName("form")[2].action = createIframe();
function createIframe(){
   ifrm = document.createElement("IFRAME"); 
   ifrm.setAttribute("src", "http://127.0.0.1/myIframe.html"); 
   ifrm.style.width = "50%"; 
   ifrm.style.height = "50%"; 
   document.body.appendChild(ifrm); 
}
```

With the above code, the iframe is spawned immediately and then clicking the button to submit the form returns an undefined page. Where am I going wrong? Many thanks for any help!

Comment: did you stop the action of the form that has the button which spawns this iframe? If you don't, then you'll spawn the iframe, then the normal form submission will occur.

Comment: I was trying to overwrite the original form action so that it called the function to spawn the iframe instead of submitting to the next page

Comment: your first line calls the createIframe() function, that's why iframe is appearing on page load itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend setting the `action` of that form to `""` and then invoking that function `onsubmit`:

```
window.onload = function() {
  var formItem = document.getElementsByTagName("form")[2];
  formItem.setAttribute('action', '');
  formItem.addEventListener('submit', createIframe, false);
}

function createIframe(){
  var ifrm = document.createElement("IFRAME"); 
  ifrm.setAttribute("src", "http://127.0.0.1/myIframe.html"); 
  ifrm.style.width = "50%"; 
  ifrm.style.height = "50%"; 
  document.body.appendChild(ifrm); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to do something like this?

```
<form onSubmit="javascript: return createIframe();" action="">
    <input type="submit" value='submit'/>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function createIframe(){
       ifrm = document.createElement("IFRAME");
       ifrm.setAttribute("src", "http://127.0.0.1/myIframe.html");
       ifrm.style.width = "50%";
       ifrm.style.height = "50%";
       document.body.appendChild(ifrm);
       return false;           
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can listen the `submit` event of that `form` element. In order to prevent the browser to continue, just return false:

```
formItem.addEventListener('submit', function (e)) {
    createIframe();
    return false;
});
```

REMARK: Your first line does two things: It sets `formItem` **and** the `action` attribute of the specified element to the **result** of `createIframe`.